# Network on home computer gets lost, adapter should be disabled/enabled to restore network access

Tags: networking, windows-10, desktop-computer

I am using Windows 10 desktop and some 2 weeks ago started to appear the following problem: network connection to the cable network gets lost randomly. It usually happens (or is detected) when I am downloading some file or viewing youtube or other online videos. Connection can be restored by resetting (disabling/enabling) local area connection network adapter. The last days it appear every 3-5 minutes, that is too frequently.

So - what should I do? What diagnostic tools are available for detecting the problem. I have used Ethereal but it is beyond imagination that I should capture all my traffic and try to detect some abnormal packs. Should I talk to my internet provider. What can it do?

I have McAfee Internet Security Suite and I guess that should exclude any problems with security.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude physical problem: check the cable for that connection. Try to move it around the rj-45 jacks. If it's possible - change it.
To exclude non-physical problem: go to the manufacturer's site of your computer/network card and download the latest drivers.
Also try to run continues ping with -t option to google.com for example and to your default gateway for that connection. See if there any drops, or the ping produces general hardware error message, that could be the difference between physical and non-physical problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I've had this, and there is a sort of hard-to-find setting (***not*** the unchecking of the "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power"  setting, which is in each of the first 20 google search pages), although that could be an issue--but because that answer is so prevalent I assume by the time someone gets here they've done that.

The setting that did it for me--and I had intermittent internet outages--was in the same Configure section of the wireless adapter, but in the Advanced tab. The setting is Selective Suspend, and you want to disable it if you see it there.

Obviously this answer only applies to USB wireless adapters.

That setting is also a global setting in the Power Options in Control Panel.